# How to resolve Jsf:Property 'not found" on type with root cause?

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, el

We have an application which uses JSF2 Primefaces and Spring. The application works fine. But this happens when i add a chart into an xhtml file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form prependId="false" id="chart">
            <p:pieChart id="pie" value="#{PhaseComponent.pieChart}" title="Tache Critique et Non Critique" style="width:400px;height:300px"  />
            </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and this the `PhaseComponent` class:

```
@Scope("session")
@Component("PhaseComponent")
public class PhaseComponent implements PhaseComponent{
    @Autowired
    private TacheService tacheService;
    private PieChartModel pieChart;
    private List<Tache> listTaches;
    public StatsImpl (){


    construct,getter and seters ...
    @Transactional
    public PieChartModel getStats()
    {
        listTaches=(List<Tache>) tacheService.loadTaches();
        int critique=0;
        int nomCritique=0;
        for(int i=0;i<listTaches.size();i++)

        {

            if(listTaches.get(i).getType().equals("Critique"))critique++;
            else nomCritique++;
        }
        pieChart.set("Tache Critique", critique);
        pieChart.set("Tache Non Critique", nomCritique);
        return pieChart;
    }

    }
```

and this the stack trace:

```
juin 04, 2014 3:49:23 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
Grave: Error Rendering View[/jsf/projet/projetChart.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /jsf/projet/projetChart.xhtml @10,135 value="#{PhaseComponent.pieChart}": Property 'pieChart' not found on type $Proxy9
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeData(PieChartRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeScript(PieChartRenderer.java:51)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeEnd(PieChartRenderer.java:36)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

juin 04, 2014 3:49:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/HCP] threw exception [/jsf/projet/projetChart.xhtml @10,135 value="#{PhaseComponent.pieChart}": Property 'pieChart' not found on type $Proxy9] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /jsf/projet/projetChart.xhtml @10,135 value="#{PhaseComponent.pieChart}": Property 'pieChart' not found on type $Proxy9
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeData(PieChartRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeScript(PieChartRenderer.java:51)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.pie.PieChartRenderer.encodeEnd(PieChartRenderer.java:36)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It is a session scoped object, which results in a proxy. Spring by default uses JDK Dynamic proxies (interface based). So you component only exposes the methods on the `PhaseComponent` interface (as a proxy is created implementing that interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add :`private PieChartModel pieChart=new pieChartModel();` for instantiate the Pie Chart Model

Answer (score 0):

PhaseComponent with small letter `phaseComponent.pieChart`

Comment: The `@Component("PhaseComponent")` makes it named `PhaseComponent` not `phseComponent`.